# How to set WM_CLASS on TkRoot in ruby

Tags: ruby, x11, tk-toolkit

I'm trying to set the 'WM_CLASS' attribute for my ruby tk application. I've tried several ways, but I think it should work like that:

```
TkRoot.new(class: 'Test')
```

But that will err with:

```
<internal:kernel>:18:in `class': wrong number of arguments (given 1, expected 0) (ArgumentError)
    from /home/ben/.gem/ruby/3.0.0/gems/tk-0.4.0/lib/tk/root.rb:40:in `block in new'
    from /home/ben/.gem/ruby/3.0.0/gems/tk-0.4.0/lib/tk/root.rb:36:in `each'
    from /home/ben/.gem/ruby/3.0.0/gems/tk-0.4.0/lib/tk/root.rb:36:in `new'
    from examples/form.rb:19:in `initialize'
    from examples/form.rb:49:in `new'
    from examples/form.rb:49:in `<main>'
```

How to do it correctly?

Comment: Looking at the source code of Ruby Tk, it appears only Tk::Frame and Tk::Toplevel can be assigned a class. I am not sure if this is actually a limitation from Tk itself and not Ruby specific, but this is what it looks like from browsing the source code.

Comment: Why do you want to set WM_CLASS? I am thinking there may be other ways to accomplish what you are trying to do.

Comment: @Casper I'm trying to set WM_CLASS, because thats how I can identify windows using my window manager. I will check out what You said about TkFrame and TkToplevel

Comment: While researching your question I found out that there is a  `group` command for Tk to group similar windows together for the window manager. If you are looking for grouping then that command might be worth checking out also.

Comment: @Casper I didn't find any group command for windows. How is the syntax?

Comment: I just think it is not possible to set the wm classname of the root window with ruby tk. Neither one can set it in tcl/tk. As You noted correctly, there is only such an option documented (in source code) for Toplevel windows and the Frame. @Casper You can make that an answer if You like to and I will accept it). Note that it seems to be possible to do in python tk using the className option when creating a root window. And it is possible to set the appname using the Tk.appname(appname) function.

Comment: I am not sure my answer is really an answer :-/ Ruby Tk seems very poorly documented and the source code is metacoded enough levels deep that it's almost impossible to figure out what it's doing. There probably is a way, we just can't figure it out. Maybe try raise an issue on the Github repo and see if you would get a better response?

Comment: Yes, I will raise an issue. Sometimes the answer is: It doesn't work and that's ok. So take the bounty, if You want it ;) .

Comment: Mailed them a TIP (see https://core.tcl-lang.org/tips/doc/trunk/doc/help.md).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tk (C api) is setting the the WM_CLASS values to the value of `argv[0]` which is the same as `$0` in ruby. So to set WM_CLASS, one has to set `$0` prior to requiring Tk. i.e.:

```
$0 = 'myWmClass'
require 'Tk'

# ... rest of the code follows here
```

This will set the application name (of WM_CLASS) to 'myWmClass' and the application class to 'MyWmClass' (so uppercase is forced here). If one wants to set the application name to something different, this can be done via `Tk.appname('someFancyName')` after requiring Tk. Note that even though Tk is required, the main window seems not to be created and so the newly created main window will have the correct appname right from the start. Also note, that using an uppercase string as application name may result in errors, as the [official tk command reference](https://tcl.tk/man/tcl8.6/TkCmd/tk.htm#M5) states.

For any other toplevel window (besides the root window), WM_CLASS can be set on construction, e.i. `TkToplevel.new(root, class: 'Toplevel')`. Trying to do that on TkRoot will currently result in an exception. (It seems however to work in the python api.)

Comment: There is also a TIP (Tcl Improvement Proposal): https://core.tcl-lang.org/tips/doc/trunk/tip/612.md